# Compare each value of a list to a another list

Tags: r

I guess the question does not tell the full story.

Let's say we have 2 list, one is a list of one word of lookup and another one is a list of multiple words

Ex.

```
data.lookup <- c('one', 'two', 'three')

data.real <- c('somewhere one day', 'mysterious elephants', 'two apple-pies', 
'love three corner', 'coffee break', 'three cats')
```

Now, we want to check if each element in data.real is containing words from data.lookup or not.

For example, 'somewhere one day' contains 'one'

Then, we save 'one' with the same index as 'somewhere one day'

Currently, I have this function which does exactly that.

```
checkFromList <- function (data.lookup, data.real) {

    df <- data.frame('sentence' = data.real, 'lookup' = 1:length(data.real))

    for (lookup in data.lookup) {

        iter <- 1 #set iteraetion

        for (sentence in data.real) {
            #If match then append
            if (grepl(lookup, sentence) == TRUE) {

                df[iter,2] <- lookup

            }

            iter <- iter + 1

        }

    }

    iter = 1 #set itereation 

    for (word in df[,2]) {

        if (is.element(word, data.lookup) == FALSE ) {

            df[iter, 2] <- 'nan'

        }

        iter <- iter + 1

    }

    return (df)

}
```

Running this function :

```
checkFromList(data.lookup, data.real)
```

Output :

[image]

I know, performance wise this function is not great (Too many for-loop).

I am asking for advise to how to improve my code. Is there anywhere i can write this better?

Also, some of you might think that there will be a problem if there are more than 2 lookup words in a sentence. The data i am working with contains only 3 words per sentence and the possibility that there will be more than 2 lookup words in the sentence is very low.

Appreciate all the help and advise !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using `stri_extract_all_regex` function from `stringi` package where we create a regex pattern using `paste0`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(data.real, paste0(data.lookup, collapse = "|"))


#[[1]]
#[1] "one"

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] "two"

#[[4]]
#[1] "three"

#[[5]]
#[1] NA

#[[6]]
#[1] "three"
```

We can create expected output of dataframe as

```
extract_words <- stri_extract_all_regex(data.real, paste0(data.lookup, 
                 collapse = "|"))
data.frame(sentence = data.real, lookup = unlist(extract_words))


#             sentence                lookup
#1    somewhere one day                   one
#2 mysterious elephants                  <NA>
#3       two apple-pies                   two
#4    love three corner                 three
#5         coffee break                  <NA>
#6           three cats                 three
```

---

We could also use `str_extract` from `stringr` or `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(data.real, paste0(data.lookup, collapse = "|"))

#[1] "one"   NA      "two"   "three" NA      "three"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using base R:

```
stack(sapply(data.lookup, function(a) grep(a, data.real, value=T)))

             values    ind
1 somewhere one day    one
2    two apple-pies    two
3 love three corner  three
4        three cats  three
```

If you want to keep the NAs:

```
stack(sapply(data.real, function(a){
    x = sapply(data.lookup, function(b) grepl(b,a))
    if(any(x)){names(which(x))} else {NA}
}))

  values                  ind
1    one    somewhere one day
2   <NA> mysterious elephants
3    two       two apple-pies
4  three    love three corner
5   <NA>         coffee break
6  three           three cats
```

Comment: You loose the rows which don't match here. It should return `NA` in case of no match and retain the rows as per OP's expected output.